# Customized sample rate to listen to videos on youtube

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, youtube

I wish I could listen to Youtube videos with a customized sample rate. The usual sample rate is 44100 or 44800. I wish I could use a smaller sample rate. Is there a way to achieve this with pulseaudio or alsa? I can already do this by downloading the audio from the video and then listening it on deadbeef player, but I wanted a more practical approach.

Comment: Do you want to slow down the sounds, or to resample them? Why?

Comment: I love the way it sounds... a sound quality between telephone and radio... around 16000...

Comment: This is more noticeable in headphones than speakers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the configuration file `~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf` if it does not exist on your system, and add

```
default-sample-rate = 16000
```

to change the default sampling rate to 16000 Hz.

This file will override, for your account only, the corresponding system wide configuration file in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`. Type `man pulse-daemon.conf` in the terminal for documentation on the configuration options.

You need to log out and then back in for the changes to take effect. Alternatively, you can stop and restart pulseaudio using the terminal: `pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start` (Thanks to mook765 for hinting to this).

Comment: `pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start` seems to be enough to load new settings, I just checked it with `pactl info`, that would avoid the need to log out and back in.

Comment: @mook765 Thank you! I added this to the answer.